# Measuring average cosine similarity between the groups

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I have the following data frame:

```
Group        Vector
1            [1 1 0 1 0 0]
1            [1 0 0 1 0 0]
1            [1 0 0 1 1 1]
1            [0 0 0 1 0 1]
2            [0 0 0 1 0 1]
2            [0 0 0 1 0 1]
2            [0 1 1 1 0 1]
2            [1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

How could I calculate the average cosine similarity within the groups? This is the expected outcome (Note I make up to numbers for the calculation)

```
Group        Vector            Average_Similarity
1            [1 1 0 1 0 0]      0.34
1            [1 0 0 1 0 0]      0.34
1            [1 0 0 1 1 1]      0.34
1            [0 0 0 1 0 1]      0.34
2            [0 0 0 1 0 1]      0.48
2            [0 0 0 1 0 1]      0.48
2            [0 1 1 1 0 1]      0.48
2            [1 1 0 0 0 1]      0.48
```

Comment: no I am interested in within group similarity

Comment: average of cosine similarity of every pair of Vectors in a group?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly  what I am looking for, so probably I will need to iterate over the rows somehow?

Comment: Do you have your data in pandas df or what?

Comment: Yes, the last column "vector" is a numpy array

Comment: What is your expected output for the two groups above?

Comment: For each group I need an average similarity or distance score. Let me also update that part

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we read data from your example like:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="|", converters = {"Vector":literal_eval})
df
   Group              Vector
0      1  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
1      1  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2      1  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
3      1  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
4      2  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
5      2  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
6      2  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
7      2  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Then try:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

df["Average_Similarity"] = df.groupby("Group")["Vector"].transform(
    lambda group: pdist(group.to_list(), metric="cosine").mean()
)
df
```

---

```
   Group              Vector  Average_Similarity
0      1  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]            0.380615
1      1  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]            0.380615
2      1  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]            0.380615
3      1  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]            0.380615
4      2  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]            0.365323
5      2  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]            0.365323
6      2  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]            0.365323
7      2  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]            0.365323
```

Comment: Well actually I get Nan values when I apply the formula

Comment: The vector is pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: What is the output  of `df['Vector'][0]`?

Comment: `[1 1 0 1 0 0]` tells me it's a string, and for any numeric calculations it must be a numpy array, like you said

Comment: @edyvedy13 Any reason not to accept the answer?

Comment: I get memory error with the proposed method

Comment: Any idea why it works for me but not fot you?

Comment: Because it is a toy example that I provided here, my real data is much larger.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a groupby apply

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np

df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(np.array([i for i in x['vec']])))

group
1    [[1.0000000000000002, 0.816496580927726, 0.577...
2    [[0.9999999999999998, 0.9999999999999998, 0.70...
```

Comment: how could I replace nans with 1s? (i.e. in case of having exact similarity)

Comment: `df[col].fillna(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Reconstruct your DataFrame so each value in the vector is placed into its own cell. Then we self merge within group and use the index to de-duplicate comparisons (i.e. we only compare 1 to 3 and not 1 to 3 and 3 to 1).

Then we calculate the cosine similarity for all rows and average within group.

```
df = pd.concat([df['Group'], pd.DataFrame(df['Vector'].tolist())], axis=1).reset_index()

m = (df.merge(df, on='Group').query('index_x > index_y')
       .drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y'])
       .set_index('Group'))

X = m.filter(like='_x')
X.columns = X.columns.str.strip('_x')

Y = m.filter(like='_y')
Y.columns = Y.columns.str.strip('_y')

m['cos'] = 1-(X*Y).sum(1).div((np.sqrt((X**2).sum(1))*np.sqrt((Y**2).sum(1))), axis=0)

m.groupby(level=0)['cos'].mean()
```

---

```
Group
1    0.380615
2    0.365323
Name: cos, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but I get a memory error

Comment: @edyvedy13 Ah, you must have a ton of groups and duplicity within those groups. In that case, the applies will be slow, but this is very memory expensive, at the cost of it being slightly more scalable with many groups.